# Better default prior for non-negative canonical polyadic decomposition of counts than Exp(1)?

Tags: bayesian, prior, count-data, decomposition, tensor

Suppose I have a instance of a random $k$-mode tensor $X_{n_1 \times \ldots \times n_k}$ of count data. I would like to perform non-negative canonical polyadic decomposition of this tensor using Bayesian parameters:

$$X_{n_1 \times \ldots \times n_k} \approx \sum_{r=1}^R \mathbf{\lambda}_r \otimes_{j=1}^k \vec{\beta}_{j,r}.$$

I've setup some prior predictive checks using $$\lambda_r \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1)$$ and $$\vec{\beta}_{j,r} \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\vec 1)$$ as priors for all $j$ and $r$. I rationalized using these exponential priors because they are the maximum differential entropy distribution over the non-negative real numbers satisfying that there is a finite expectation. I'm not sure if I should further account for the fact that the data is count data, which may tend to have their own distribution.

Is there a better choice of default prior(s) to choose for these parameters assuming that it will be used to explore count data? By "better", I mean that *potentially* the product of exponential variables might have a distribution that doesn't resemble common distributions of count data.